# Select Query Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 4 tables: Team Player and  Birth of a player (in which I have the city and Country).

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the "Team" table twice, and join between them.

```
SELECT Game_Date,
   Player.First_Name || ' ' || Player.Last_Name AS "PLAYER NAME",
   UPPER(Team1.Team_Name) AS "HOME TEAM",
   UPPER(Team2.Team_Name) AS "VISITING TEAM",
   Team1.Team_City ||' '|| Team1.Team_Name as "TEAM",
   Birth_Place1.Country
FROM Game
     JOIN Team Team1 ON Game.Team_Home_ID = Team1.Team_ID
     JOIN Team Team2 ON Game.Team_Visitor_ID = Team2.Team_ID
     JOIN Player Player1 ON Player1.Team_ID = Team1.Team_ID
     JOIN Player Player2 ON Player2.Team_ID = Team2.Team_ID
     JOIN Birth_Place Birth_Place1 ON Birth_Place1.Birth_Place_ID = Player1.Birth_Place_ID
     JOIN Birth_Place Birth_Place2 ON Birth_Place2.Birth_Place_ID = Player2.Birth_Place_ID
WHERE Birth_Place1.Country = Birth_Place2.Country
     AND Season = '2015-2016'
     AND Game_Date = '10-10-2015'
     AND Birth_Place1.Country NOT IN ('CAN', 'USA')
ORDER BY Birth_Place1.Country;
```

Not sure if this is the exact correct request, but you get the idea: the trick is in the "Birth_Place1.Country = Birth_Place2.Country" WHERE clause.

Also rewrote the WHERE clause over Country since it looked like it only filtered out two countries.

You might consider reviewing your architecture a bit, especially the Birth_Place table: I guess knowing the player's country right in the Player table makes sense if you intend to use it as a filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works except that the correct players are displayed but each player appears 2 times

Comment: You mean once as away and once as home, or? Anyway, can you add the DISTINCT keyword after SELECT and see if it's enough?

Comment: No not even, the first player appears 4 times but the ones from Sweden are good

Comment: I tried the distinct but there is only 4 players that appear

Comment: Yes, that request only retrieves players from the home team, sorry. One way to retrieve players from the away team would be to duplicate the request and then union the 2, but there must be an easier way. I'll come back to it tomorrow, sorry I couldn't help you more for now. I hope somebody else has a better answer in the meantime :/

Comment: No worries, you actually helped me a lot.
I finally figured it out and couldn`t have done it without your help.
Thank you very much Anthony

Comment: Well, you know what to do if you are satisfied with an answer ;)
Glad I could help.